# How to create a CMBlockBufferRef from NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata, core-media

I am struggling (getting memory errors, or apparently not correctly deallocating memory) trying to create a CMBlockBufferRef filled with data from an existing NSData (or NSMutableData).
I would be happy with a solution that copies data, but ideally I would be looking at a solution that would use the underlying NSData bytes and keep a strong reference to the NSData object until the CMBlockBuffer is deallocated.

Answer (score 3):

Only for a read-only buffer referring a `NSData` (of course, without copying), I've just found a way to achieve it.

```
static void releaseNSData(void *o, void *block, size_t size)
{
    NSData *data = (__bridge_transfer NSData*) o;
    data = nil; // Assuming ARC is enabled
}

OSStatus createReadonlyBlockBuffer(CMBlockBufferRef *result, NSData *data)
{
    CMBlockBufferCustomBlockSource blockSource =
    {
        .version       = kCMBlockBufferCustomBlockSourceVersion,
        .AllocateBlock = NULL,
        .FreeBlock     = &releaseNSData,
        .refCon        = (__bridge_retained void*) data,
    };
    return CMBlockBufferCreateWithMemoryBlock(NULL, (uint8_t*) data.bytes, data.length, NULL, &blockSource, 0, data.length, 0, result);
}
```

Comment: This is the code everyone should be using in order to avoid ARC dealloc races since CMBlockBufferCreateWithMemoryBlock is just referencing to the NSData objects bytes without retaining it. Awesome!!

Comment: Could you please take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/69632925/5709159